# How can I detect blur event in React Native tab component?

Tags: react-native, tabs

I'm using rmc-tabs for tab component in React Native.
I'm using video component and want to pause the video when I move to other tab, but I don't know how to do this.
How can I get the blur event in rmc-tabs or are there any other ways to handle blur event in React Native video or view?

Comment: does rmc-tab provides `onChangeTab` method ? if yes you can use this method

Comment: The problem is I want to get the event in a nested component.
There is NavigationEvent in react-navigation. I want sth like this one.

Comment: can you add that code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are using `createTabNavigator` or `createBottomTabNavigator` you can use `NavigationEvents` within the screens inside TabNavigator which allow you to listen to

```
onWillFocus : before focusing a tab;
onDidFocus : after focusing a tab;
onWillBlur : before losing focus on a tab;
onDidBlur : after losing focus on a tab;
```